# How to use the RegexMatcher in SparkNLP

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark-sql, nlp, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

Here is the case. I want to run SparkNLP on Jupyterlab with Scala kernel. I want to use the `RegexMatcher` annotation. I saved the pattern in a file named `patterns.txt` on s3 bucket. And I tried the implementation below

```
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.util.io.ExternalResource
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.util.io.ReadAs.LINE_BY_LINE
val document = new DocumentAssembler().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("document")
val regexmatcher = new RegexMatcher().
  setInputCols(Array("document")).
  setOutputCol("match").
  setStrategy("MATCH_ALL").
  setRules(ExternalResource("s3://bucket_name/patterns.txt", LINE_BY_LINE, Map("format" -> "text", "delimiter" -> " ")))
val pipeline_regex = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(document, regexmatcher))
val regex_match = pipeline_regex.fit(dev_data)
regex_match.transform(dev_data).select('match).show(false)
```

However, it seems thit doesn't work at all, and `patterns.txt` are not used. How to fix it.

Comment: Where is your  variable `dev_data` declared? I cannot see it in your code. What type is it ?

Comment: @CatalinaChircu the `dev_data` is declared earlier. It is a dataframe.

Comment: Is there any specific error you can add? The more details you provide the better response you can get. Not working at all doesn't really mean anything. I need to see how the DataFrame looks like, what is inside patterns.txt, etc.

Comment: @Maziyar Thanks. No error, just returns empty matches. Below is an example of my regex, key pair in the pattern.txt:
`^(?i)application\\s+for motion-prefix`

Comment: Did you mean your regex to have Negative Look ahead?

```^(?!)application\\s+for motion-prefix```